# Comparing Two Sets of Data, Cyclic Input, Different Measurement Times

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have two sensors measuring temperature of two items that have a slightly different treatment (to see if affects their thermal properties). The temperature is cyclic in that every day it goes up and down. The temperature of both items is measured every 30 minutes but not necessarily at the same times i.e. Item A measured at 2:34pm, Item B measured at 2:40pm and so on.
I want to check two things:

1. Is the treatment causing a change in the temperature
2. if 1) = true, what is the mean difference caused by the treatment

There is an added complication to the temperature in that the effect, if present, should cause a larger difference when the temperature is warmer during the day. How would I isolate my data for warmer temperatures? The problem as I see it is that I can't select the data directly from both sensors based purely on time because the measurements aren't recorded at exactly the same time. I also can't select the data from both sensors where the temperature > e.g. 20C (because if the treated Item has in fact a lower temperature, I would be excluding this from the analysis: if the effect caused the temperature to be 2C lower, I would need to include data from > 18C

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JItpv.png)

Any guidance greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Anybody got any pointers?

Comment: Anybody any ideas??

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestion as to how to go about this?